# Are old nodes automatically archived over time?

Tags: nodes

I just went to a site that I haven't touch in a while and I see this on the homepage:
The requested page "/" could not be found.

I went into Administration » Configuration » System
and saw that the Default front page was set as: /node/1
When I tried to pull up that node, I got a page not found error:
The requested page "/node/1" could not be found

I suppose it's possible that someone else who has access to the site deleted this node accidentally, but I'm just wondering if it may have been auto-archived or something instead.

Are there hackers that gain access to sites and then just delete their front page? Or should I be pointing the finger at the other people who have access to the site?

Comment: Also, are there logs of DELETEs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drupal does not archive or otherwise delete or modify content automatically over time. There are a few possibilities as to what happened to node1 including:

- An administrator or someone with permission to delete nodes of that content type deleted it
- there is a rule or other module configuration that deletes nodes after a certain amount of time
- Node 1 was deleted a long time ago and someone changed the front page after the fact (not likely as I think drupal verifies the path when you save that setting)

Drupal does keep a record of when nodes are deleted in the watchdog table. The watchdog table has a UI which can be found at /admin/reports/dblog. You can filter this list by type, but note that Drupal only stores a finite number of rows in this table with First In First Out as a rule. So it's possible that the record of node 1 being deleted has also been deleted.